# Adding a ScrollPane to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I got a problem with this portion of code trying to get a ScrollPane on a JTextArea

```
showArea = new JTextArea();
showArea.setBounds(5, 145, 625, 310);
showArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
showArea.setText(cat.getValidOffers());
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(showArea);  
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
panel.add(scrollPane);
panel.add(showArea);
```

I really don't know what is wrong with this code, the scrollpane doesn't show at all.

Comment: all components are specifically in a precise position determined by a setBounds call on all components managing to get this.


//http://i.stack.imgur.com/SeIpX.jpg

now if i remove the setBounds on the textarea how can i manage to get it in the same position as shown above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I really don't know what is wrong with this, the scrollpane doesn't show at all."

Remove this `panel.add(showArea);`. You only need to add the scroll pane. A component can only have one parent container. When you add the text area to the panel, it is removed from the scroll pane

Also set the size of the text area like this

```
new JTextArea(20, 30);  .. rows, columns
```

And remove this

```
showArea.setBounds(5, 145, 625, 310);
```

Comment: tryed it but the textArea doesn't show at all this way, same the scrollpane

Comment: posted a comment with an image under the answer above of the other guy can you pls see it and get me a solution for this particular case ?

Comment: As Deepak mentioned in his comment, you _really_ should use layout managers instead of a null layout. Have a look at [**Laying out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Since you're already this far ahead, I'll tell you what's wrong. Since you're using a null layout, every component needs to have its bounds set. Since you're only adding the scroll pane and not the text area, set the bounds of the scroll pane, instead.

Comment: amazing mate really thanks you saved me so much time :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the bounds for the textarea. 
Also since you have already added the textarea inside scrollpane, you don't need to add it to the panel.

Comment: all components are specifically in a precise position determined by a setBounds call on all components managing to get this.


//http://i.stack.imgur.com/SeIpX.jpg

now if i remove the setBounds on the textarea how can i manage to get it in the same position as shown above ?

Comment: Use a layout manager instead of setting bounds. Since scrollpane is the parent, its position determines the position of textarea.